# Problems implementing Java's Queue interface?

Tags: java, interface, queue

I am getting an error showing that aClass must be declared abstract. Is there a way I can just implement a Queue without having to have my class be abstract?

```
public class aClass<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Queue<T> {}
```

Yields error:
Error:(3, 8) java: aClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method peek() in java.util.Queue

Comment: Have you tried overriding abstract method peek()?

Comment: Why would I need to override it exactly? Shouldn't it be returning the the Element that the Queue holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue` is an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), which means it doesn't provide any implementation for its methods. All an interface is is a contract that the implementing class will provide those methods. If you want to be able to be able to instantiate a queue, you either need to provide all those methods yourself, or use one of the built in classes which implements `Queue`. You can find a list of those by looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

An example of what this would look like is:

```
Queue myQueue = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you!